# Finding URI in Child Theme

Tags: urls, child-theme

Which is best way to find URI in child Theme.

```
<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>
```

Below given code works but it has "stylesheet" in it, sounds like its a hake to find URI. Is this the only solution ?

```
<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>
<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `stylesheet` is for child themes, `template` for parent themes. Andrew Nacin has explained that [recently on wp-hackers](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2012-November/044730.html):

> child themes
>   were originally just `style.css` and `functions.php`. That's why "template"
>   refers to the parent theme and "stylesheet" refers to the child theme.